# weighted graph from the sparse matrix

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I interested to create a weighted graph from the sparse matrix of weights.

The following code works for small examples, but to the graph, with few thousands of node, it does not work.

```
arrayR = {{1, 2} -> 1.6608834828359216`, {1, 3} -> 
    1.3176250784021715`, {2, 1} -> 1.6608834828359216`, {2, 3} -> 
    3.8979590937707167`, {2, 4} -> 2.058499550409593`, {3, 1} -> 
    1.3176250784021715`, {3, 2} -> 3.8979590937707167`, {3, 4} -> 
    1.0569052092863416`, {4, 2} -> 2.058499550409593`, {4, 3} -> 
    1.0569052092863416`, {_, _} -> 0};

WeightedAdjacencyGraph[SparseArray[arrayR /. {0 -> Infinity}]]
```

Any suggestion on how to do it with big graphs?

Comment: try `WeightedAdjacencyGraph[SparseArray[Most @ arrayR, {numberofnodes,  numberofnodes}, ∞]]`?

Comment: thank you, this approach more efficient and save around 15% of running time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has a function for this.

[image]

Performance test:

```
g = RandomGraph[{5000, 20000}, EdgeWeight -> RandomReal[1, 20000]];

wam = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g];

IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[wam]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.014, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

A random graph with 1000 nodes and 5000 edges

```
SeedRandom[1]
arrayR = Append[Thread[RandomSample[Tuples[Range[1000], {2}], 5000] -> 
     RandomReal[1, 5000]], {_, _} -> 0];

WeightedAdjacencyGraph[SparseArray[Most@arrayR, {1000, 1000}, ∞]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

versus

```
WeightedAdjacencyGraph[SparseArray[arrayR /. 0 -> ∞, {1000, 1000}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

(Still on version 9, so cannot use `IGraph/M`)